# SQlite Design Advice

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design

What is the best way of dealing with foreign keys in a table that can be from two different tables?
To be more clear:
`T1(id,c1,c2)` - c1 and c2 are from either T2 or T3
`T2(id,name)`
`T3(id,name)`
Consider T2 and T3 have to be different tables. And if `c1` is from `T1` (for example), `c2` can be from either `T2` or `T3`.

Should I:

1. Create a new table that holds the associations and have `c1` and `c2` point to an id from that table? i.e. `T4(id,id_from_T1,id_from_T2_or_T3,what_table)`

2. Create 2 columns, `c1_parent`, `c2_parent` and make a convention like if it is 1 then it's from `T2` if it's 2 then it's from `T3`.

Or is there an entirely new better way?

Thank you.

Comment: Do T2 and T3 have the same structure?

Comment: No, I'd have to use IF and CASE. But for the moment they both share than name column which is all I need. Not sure in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a good mechanism for guaranteeing that `id` is not duplicated across all three tables. So you're better off with `T1` as:

```
T1(id,c1_tbl,c1_id,c2_tbl,c2_id)
```

Alternatively, refactor your table design so that a given foreign key can only come from one specific table. (I can't give specifics because you didn't describe the goals of this schema.)

Either of these will make life easier when it comes time to `JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you Mike. But can you condition JOINs based on a column?

Comment: Sure. I don't write a lot of SQL myself, but I'd imagine it would be something like `SELECT ... FROM T1, T2 WHERE T1.c1_tbl = 1 INNER JOIN T1.c1_id = T2.id` or so. The Django [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) framework uses something like this. It creates a table that represents each table that can be used in this way, assigning each table an ID number. Then you can reference any record in any table with a table-ID and ID-within-table combination (a "generic foreign key"), allowing the IDs in the tables to be standard auto-increment fields.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional foreign keys are non-standard SQL. You should find a way to amalgamate your NAMES tables. If necessary, NAMES could have a composite key.

For example, instead of DEFENDERS and ATTACKERS tables, you'd have amalgamated PLAYERS table with a column that indicated whether the player was offense or defense:

```
                          PLAYERS
                          OffenseOrDefense
                          PlayerName
                          primary key(OffenseOrDefense,PlayerName)


                         DREAM TEAM
                         position
                         offenseOrDefense
                         playerName

                         foreign key(offenseOrDefense,PlayerName) references PLAYERS(offenseOrDefense,PlayerName)
```